# Gluon mobile "Missing CAP cache" when building for Android

Tags: android, javafx, gluon, graalvm

I'm testing the gluon mobile library with a basic template project provided with the Gluon plugin for IntelliJ.

The sample app run without any problem but when building for a native app on Android, I have the following error :

> Missing CAP cache value for: NativeCodeInfo:AArch64LibCHelperDirectives:StructInfo:CPUFeatures:StructFieldInfo:fDMB_ATOMICS

Launching several times, the problem appears for different values : fDMB_ATOMICS,

- NativeCodeInfo:AArch64LibCHelperDirectives:StructInfo:CPUFeatures:StructFieldInfo:fDMB_ATOMICS
- NativeCodeInfo:PosixDirectives:ConstantInfo:CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID

I am beginner using gluon so I think some library is missing but I have no idea what is it...

Does someone have any idea?

Thank you for advance.

Comment: See [docs](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_platforms), you need to use GraalVM 22.1.0.1 from https://github.com/gluonhq/graal/releases/tag/gluon-22.1.0.1-Final. What is your GluonFX plugin version?

Comment: Hi José.

I am using the last version of GluonFX (1.0.16). 
I was using a GraalVM version 22.3.0 from the official website instead the customized gluon version.
Switching to it, it's working without any problem.
Thank you for your help. :)